# operator+= between custom complex type and std::complex

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, operator-keyword

I want my custom complex type to be able to interact with std::complex, but in certain cases, the compiler do not convert my type to std::complex.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Expr>
class CpxScalarExpression 
{
public:
    inline std::complex< double > eval() const { return static_cast<Expr const&>(*this).eval(); }
    
    inline operator std::complex< double >() const { return static_cast<Expr const&>(*this).eval(); }
};

class CpxScalar : public CpxScalarExpression<CpxScalar>
{
public:
    CpxScalar() : m_value(0) {}
    CpxScalar(const double value) : m_value(value) {}
    CpxScalar(const double real_value, const double imag_value) : m_value(real_value, imag_value) {}
    CpxScalar(const std::complex< double > value) : m_value(value) {}
    template<typename Expr>
    CpxScalar(const CpxScalarExpression< Expr >& expr) : m_value(expr.eval()) {}
public:
    inline std::complex< double > eval() const { return m_value; }
private:
    std::complex< double > m_value;
};

int main()
{
    CpxScalar a(10,-5);
    //std::complex< double >* b = reinterpret_cast< std::complex< double >* >(&a);
    std::complex< double > b = a;
    b += a;
    
    //std::cout << b->real() << " " << b->imag();
    std::cout << b.real() << " " << b.imag();
}
```

The compiler fails at deducing which operator+= to call and returns the following error

```
est.cpp:50:4: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::complex<double>’ and ‘CpxScalar’)
   50 |  b += a;
      |  ~~^~~~
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/complex:1287:7: note: candidate: ‘std::complex<double>& std::complex<double>::operator+=(double)’
 1287 |       operator+=(double __d)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/complex:1287:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘CpxScalar’ to ‘double’
 1287 |       operator+=(double __d)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/complex:1329:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp> std::complex<double>& std::complex<double>::operator+=(const std::complex<_Tp>&)’
 1329 |         operator+=(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/complex:1329:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:50:7: note:   ‘CpxScalar’ is not derived from ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’
   50 |  b += a;
      |       ^
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: As a quick FYI: All member functions defined inside of a class definition are implicitly `inline`. Explicitly marking them as such is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your own overload for the operator is the way to go.

However, there's a few things to keep in mind:

- Since you already have a cast available, all you have to do is to use it and let the regular operator take it from there.
- Since the type that is meant to "pose" as `std::complex` is  `CpxScalarExpression<Expr>`, then that should be the one the overload operates on.
- `std::complex`'s `operator+=()` normally allows you to add together complex values of different types, so we should maintain that. Meaning the operator should be templated on the incoming `std::complex`'s components type.
- We need to make sure to return *exactly* whatever `std::complex`'s `operator+=` wants to return. Using `decltype(auto)` as the return type of the overload provides you with just that.

Putting all of that together, we land at:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Expr>
constexpr decltype(auto) operator+=(
        std::complex<T>& lhs,
        const CpxScalarExpression<Expr>& rhs) {
    return lhs += std::complex<double>(rhs);
}
```

Dropping that into the code you posted makes it work just as expected, and should give you feature parity with `std::complex`'s `operator+=()`.

Answer (score 0):

A custom operator for `+=` works with your example:

```
[[maybe_unused]] constexpr static inline std::complex<double> operator+=(
        const std::complex<double>& lhs,
        const CpxScalar&            rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs + rhs.eval();
}
```

Comment: What're the `inline` and `static` supposed to accomplish here?

Comment: You want to return a reference in the `+=` rather than a value, else you get a lot of 'no-op' expressions where any calculated value is just discarded. As it stands this code will not work, in a confusing way.

Comment: @Frank: you probably won't need inline because the compiler will inline it anyway, but I like precise code. Same thing for static, there is only one copy needed in all translation units, so why state otherwise?

Comment: @MicroVirus: why do you get a list of no-ops?